# Compare image background

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, compare

The background image is already set in the Xcode project, but when the button gets clicked it changes, so I want to check whether or not the background image `80red.png` is the same as the button's background just clicked.

```
-(IBAction)buttonChange:(id)sender {

    redImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"80red.png”];

    UIImage *ButtonColour = [sender backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal];       

    NSData *ButtonColourData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ButtonColour);
    NSData *redImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(redImage);

    if ([ButtonColourData isEqual: redImageData]) {

        // if images are the same
        NSLog(@"Images are the same");    
    }    
}
```

I don't understand why my code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you have mistakes in syntax of code.

redImage isn't link to object UIImage class - You had to write `UIImage *redImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"80red.png"];`

Next:

When you do a comparison dates of images, you comparing size the images, but different images may be the same size. Better compare the images on their content.

I pretended to your situation and that's what I got:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.


UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2, 2)];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"80red.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self buttonChange:button];

return YES;
```

}

-(IBAction)buttonChange:(id)sender {

```
UIImage *redImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"80red.png"];

UIImage *ButtonColour = [sender backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal];

//NSData *ButtonColourData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ButtonColour);
//NSData *redImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(redImage);

if ([redImage isEqual: ButtonColour]) {

    // if images are the same
    NSLog(@"Images are the same");

}
```

}

I hope my advice will help you.

P.S. Sorry for my english =)

Comment: @user2643679  if my advice did help you, please to like it:)